# List multiplication in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I need to multiply different lists to calculate areas of irregular polygons.

```
X = [1,1,1,1,1,1]
Y = [5,4,3,2,1,0]
```

This means that coordinates from point 1 are `(1,5)`, for point 2 are `(1,4)` and so on. To calculate the area I need to multiply `X[i] * Y[i+1]` which is equal to `1 * 4, 1 * 3, 1 * 2` and exlude the last multiplication, such as `1 * empty`.

How can I do this?

Comment: "How can I do this?" What have you tried?

Comment: What should your output look like? What have you tried? Please [edit] the question.

Comment: With the map function and a good slicing of your list, it should be easy to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, in my understanding, you need a lag between `X` and `Y`, where the first element of `Y` is excluded, and the last element of `X` is excluded. In other words, you need something like:

```
[(1, 4), (1, 3), (1, 2), (1, 1), (1, 0)]
```

You can produce the above via:

```
zipped = zip(X[:-1], Y[1:])
```

and you can compute the products of each pair like so:

```
[a * b for a, b in zipped]
```

Of course, if `X` and `Y` were numpy arrays, you could do this much more efficiently:

```
>>> X[:-1] * Y[1:]
array([4, 3, 2, 1, 0])
```

Comment: To be honest you don't even need to slice X. `zip(X, Y[1:])` will provide the same output since `zip` stops when it consumes the shortest iterable. Not slicing X saves some memory.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
[x * y for x, y in zip(X, Y[1:])]
```

would do it.  But you should really use Numpy for anything non-trivial.

Comment: I cannot use numpy solely "Python", I know that with numpy this would be easy. Thanks!